# Ttk Indeterminate progress bar on button press

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading, ttk

I am trying to create a progress bar that runs as long as my function is running to show the user that things are happening and not just frozen. My function (generate_reports) makes queries to the database and writes to CSV files. Here is an abstract version of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from billing import generate_reports

class app:
  def __init__(self, root):
    self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = '4 4 12 12')
    self.mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
    ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text = "Generate Billing Reports", command = self.do_reports).grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky = (W, E))
  
  def do_reports(self, *args):
     pbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.mainframe, orient = HORIZONTAL, mode = 'indeterminate')
     pbar.grid(row = 4, column = 3, sticky = (W, E))
     t1 = threading.Thread(target = generate_reports, args = [start, end])
     t1.start()
     pbar.start()
     t1.join()
     pbar.stop()
     return

root = Tk()
BillingApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

With this code, the progress bar doesn't pop up until after the generate_reports thread is completed and it is unmoving. If I remove the join, everything works fine but it never stops loading. How can I make the loading bar run for only the duration of the generate_reports thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh welcome to the fun world of event driven programming :). You can't use `join` here, the point of that function is to block until the thread is done and the whole point of using a thread is to avoid blocking the mainloop. You have 2 choices: either set up the GUI to constantly poll the thread to see if it's still running, or set up the thread to send a message back to the GUI when it's done. This latter option is probably the cleanest, and it's often done using tkinter's event mechanism.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

def generate_reports(start, end):
    print("provide a mcve next time!")
    time.sleep(5)

def run_report(root, *args):
    generate_reports(*args)
    root.event_generate("<<PhishDoneEvent>>") # yes, this is using tkinter in a thread, but some tkinter methods are ok to use in threads

class BillingApp:
  def __init__(self, root):
    self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = '4 4 12 12')
    self.mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
    ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text = "Generate Billing Reports", command = self.do_reports).grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky = (W, E))
    root.bind("<<PhishDoneEvent>>", self.report_done)

  def do_reports(self, *args):
    # note this makes a new widget with every click ... this is bad. Refactor to reuse the widget. 
    self.pbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.mainframe, orient = HORIZONTAL, mode = 'indeterminate')
    self.pbar.grid(row = 4, column = 3, sticky = (W, E))
    start, end = 4,5
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = run_report, args = [root, start, end])
    t1.start()
    self.pbar.start()

  def report_done(self, event=None):
    self.pbar.stop()
    Label(self.mainframe, text="report done").grid(row = 4, column = 3)

root = Tk()
BillingApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, looks like event driven programming might be something I should dive into!

Comment: can you explain why you pass event=None to report_done()?

Comment: The bind method requires the that function accepts an event. The `=None` part makes the event optional, which is a habit that allows you to call that same function from the event bind as I have it now *or* as a normal method *or* from a Button. So you could add a button to fire that method if you wanted to. Not really useful here but can be, for example if you want to do have pressing return do the same thing as clicking "OK".

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have accepted the answer above. However, I would post my answer since it is not based on threading, which I think is simpler and may be more suitable:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os



root = Tk()

# I set the length and maximum as shown to demonstrate the process in the 
# proceeding function
progress = Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL,
            length = 200/5, maximum=200/5, mode = 'determinate')

# Function 


def my_func():
    t=0
    r= 1/5   
    for i in range(200):
        print(i)
        t=t+r
        progress['value'] = t
        root.update_idletasks()
  

progress.pack()

# Button
Button(root, text = 'Start', command = bar).pack(pady = 10)


mainloop()
```