# Display simple loading animation while function is running in tkinter window

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, loading, python-itertools

I am creating a tkinter GUI that has a function to import large MAT files for plotting. Some MAT files I need to import are very large and can take a long time. I want a loading animation to play on in the main window while the function is running and then disappear after the function has imported the large file. This function is activated on a button press. Here is what I have found online for a loading animation, but it starts and does not stop when the function is completed. I haven't even tried to display it in the main window yet.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import itertools
import scipy.io as spio
import threading
import time
import sys
main_win = tkinter.Tk()
main_win.geometry = ("800x500")
done = False

#here is the animation
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rloading ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\rDone!     ')

def chooseFile():
   t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
   t.start()
   main_win.sourceFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=main_win, title=" please select MAT file")
   my_path = main_win.sourceFile
   testread = spio.loadmat(my_path, squeeze_me=True, struct_as_record=False)
   time.sleep(10)
   done = True
   print('file imported')

filebutton=tkinter.Button(main_win, text="choose MAT file", command=chooseFile)


main_win.mainloop()
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: That's a (very outdated) terminal animation, not a GUI animation. Did you have GUI animation you want to use? How about the standard tkinter progressbar?

Comment: @Novel I tried to work with the tkinter progressbar with no luck. It really doesn't matter the animation, just something to tell the user its running behind the scenes.

Comment: @coderoftheday updated, sorry.

Comment: @AKBRC maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65084936/2229945